# Spring data redis 2.0.2.RELEASE eclipse import error

Tags: eclipse, maven-plugin, spring-data-redis

Download spring data redis 2.0.2.RELEASE source code from Github, import with eclipse(Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)) [import - Maven -Existing Maven Projects].

There were still some problems after resovled the problems lombok and org.apache.maven.archiver.MavenArchiver.getManifes:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Cannot infer type arguments for ConvertingCursor<>  DefaultStringRedisConnection.java   /spring-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection  line 3246   Java Problem
The method any(Class<byte[]>) is ambiguous for the type LettuceConnectionUnitTestSuite.LettuceConnectionUnitTests   LettuceConnectionUnitTestSuite.java /spring-data-redis/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce  line 172    Java Problem
The method any(Class<byte[]>) is ambiguous for the type LettuceConnectionUnitTestSuite.LettuceConnectionUnitTests   LettuceConnectionUnitTestSuite.java /spring-data-redis/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce  line 172    Java Problem
The method defaultNullTo(Supplier<Object>) in the type LettuceResult.LettuceResultBuilder<T,Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Supplier<R>)   LettuceConnection.java  /spring-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce  line 132    Java Problem
Type mismatch: cannot convert from LettuceResult<T,Object> to LettuceResult<T,R>    LettuceConnection.java  /spring-data-redis/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/redis/connection/lettuce  line 123    Java Problem
```

Did Spring projects need special import methods, I try to use STS to import, and there are similar problems.

Any Advice Or Help?
1. What IDE should be used to import the Spring data redis project?
2. How resolve these errors above after eclipse import?

Comment: Please, edit your question and write it in English

Comment: Has been converted by Google Translate.